# Error with 'REACT_APP_API_BASE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i am executing the command REACT_APP_API_BASE=https://ip/api yarn start on Linux system it works fine and i can access the frontend of the application but same command doesnt work on windows and throws and error "'REACT_APP_API_BASE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." How can the same command be used in windows-

Comment: What shell are you using? `Cmd.exe`? Powershell? Git bash?

Comment: Yes i am using cmd.exe

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe

Comment: i tried it but doesnot work for me i donw know if i am right
C:\abc>cmd /V /C "set EDITOR=vim&& echo !EDITOR!" vim
vim vim

C:\abc>cmd /v /c "set REACT_APP_API_BASE=https://url/api yarn start /